# Obtain an upper bound for the error incurred in approximating $f(0.1)$ for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ by $P_5(0.1)$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Obtain an upper bound for the error incurred in approximating $f(0.1)$ for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ by $P_5(0.1)$

**My approach**: Find Maclaurin series $P_5(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$
According to remainder theorem $|R_5(0.1)|\leq \frac{M\cdot(0.1)^6}{6!}$. But how can I get $M$ because I didn't know what $M$ is the upper bound for $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ in the $x\in[0,0.1]$. Besides can anyone help me to understand general concept to find $M$. Because it's easy to get $M$ for $\sin(x),\cos(x),e^x$ function but I don't know how to find it for other function.

Any hint or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Note that in this case
$$f(x)-P_5(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}=\frac{x^6}{1-x}.$$
P.S. By the way $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ so what is
$M=\max_{x\in [0,0.1]}|f^{(6)}(x)|$?

Comment: Sir $f^{(6)}(0)=\frac{6!}{(1)^{7}}=720$ and $ f^{(6)}(0.1)=\frac{6!}{(1-0.1)^{7}}=1505.9412$.Can we take $M=1506??$ @Robert Z

Comment: Is it enough to check for end points only?? @emonhossain Sir

Comment: Yes, $x\to \frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$ is positive and strictly increasing in $[0,0.1]$ hence the maximum value is attained at $0.1$.

Comment: Ohh! Really you help me a lot @Robert Z sir.Now I really feel that I can do it for all other function